# how can i get the the attribute label from the attribute value in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I got the attribute value 232 from the below code

```
    $_product->getData('farben');
```

How I get its label from this value?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please try this code

1. First you have to load the products

   `$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();`
2. In the product listing page ,there will be a foreach loop for listing the products like this

   `foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)`
3. Your code will be inside this loop.Place the below code at a place where ever you want to display the attribute label.

`$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: getResource is deprecated in Magento 2.3.0

Comment: @DivyaMuralidharan this code return attributes value not label

Comment: is there an optimized way to get the option label, instead of using the for loop with bulk products?

Answer (score 13):

```
 $_product = $productObject; //get product object

 $optionId = 232;   
 $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code');
 if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
 }
 echo $optionText;
```

Comment: how can we get custom attribute label in custom module block using phtml file,actually i am able to get custom attribute value.

Comment: This run faster than accepted answer

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score -6):

```
$product = $this->objectFactory->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$attributes = $product->getAttributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
     label => __($attribute->getStoreLabel()),
     'value' => $value, //attribute Value
     'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(), //attribute Code
}
```

Comment: How is this accepted? It has errors and incorrect syntax.