# Magento 2 - Get simple product attributes on Grouped product detailpage

Tags: magento2, attributes, grouped-products

I'm trying to get the **attributes values** of the **simple products** in a grouped product to display on the detailpage (of the grouped product), but it is not working.

At the moment i have the following code in *Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml*.

```
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>          
  <?php $item = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getId()); 
    $item->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($item) .' <br />';
```

I'm getting the value of the attribute now, but it looks like it's not "resetting" the value. I have 3 simple products where only 2 of them have a value for the attribute set in the admin backend. Nevertheless does the third product has the attribute value of the second one.

I hope anyone could help me to fix this problem (and maybe with better code then the objectManager). Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like your attribute type is **select**, isn't it?

Comment: @PYYick Yes, the attribute type is dropdown (select).

Comment: @PYYick Should i make it an other type then? Or do you have any other solutions?

Comment: Just rewrite the codes is OK.

Comment: @PYYick What do you mean with "rewrite the codes"? Is it possible that you provide an example code?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141360/how-can-i-get-the-the-attribute-label-from-the-attribute-value-in-magento-2